# AWS API Gateway, Lambda, JavaScript CORS

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying use java script to access an AWS api gateway to call a lambda with passing through headers.
Testing via postman works fine.

[image]
But then I attempt to access via java script 
[image]

I get the following:

'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,Access-Control-Allow-Headers,Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
[image]

I have added in acaH and acaO to the header mapping for the option in AWS api as suggested in a number of articles, saved and redeployed to no affect.
[image]

I have enabled CORS on both the GET and OPTION methods to no avail.

I will freely admit I just barely understand the CORS concept, am I missing something very obvious?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the API from a `null` origin.

As stated in the console error `Access from origin 'null' has been blocked`, a `null` origin value typically indicates that the request is either coming from a file on your computer (rather than from a website) or as a result of a redirect operation.

Comment: Hi Khalid, thanks for your reply. Yes, I have been accessing from a local file for testing. I have also tried using from and S3 bucket set to use as a static web site but still get the null origin.

Comment: This could be due to preflight request caching. Preflight requests are cached up to 5 minutes in most browsers, except for Firefox which can cache preflight requests up to 24 hours. So, you could try clearing the browser cache or trying a different browser.

Comment: Unfortunately clearing cache, different browsers, different PC's hasn't resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You better check your lambda function instead. Sometimes, that `cors` error will be return when some errors exposed inside your function.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a Lambda function and AWS API calling it, the settings in AWS API may not return the headers required for CORS. Even you set it in the API settings it may be overwritten by Lambda return.

The solution is in that case you to return the headers in the LAMBDA function.

Here is an example from my LAMBDA python code. You can use a similar solution in any language.

Just return the required headers for CORS yourself.

```
        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'headers': {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods,Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,X-Requested-With',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'DELETE,GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,PATCH,POST,PUT',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true'
            },
            'body': json.dumps({
                "customerID": data['customerID']
            })
        }
```